# uitabbarcontroller 'moreviewcontroller' orientation

Tags: iphone, uiinterfaceorientation, tabbarcontroller

I could rotate my tabbarcontroller app in every orientation previously - however - as I have now exceeded the set amount of fixed tabbaritems the tabbarcontroller has automatically added the'moreviewcontroller' and now the app wont change its orientation (I imagine as the more view controller has not been set the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" return value.

where if possible can I set it to allow for device orientation.

or is this not supported?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should still just handle it. Are you absolutely sure all of your view controllers are returning YES for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:? Are they all the top level VCs that are in your UITabBarController, or are any of them now wrapped in something else which isn't supporting rotation?

Comment: ahh, over looked the fact that I had created an extra tab bar item in IB however never had assigned it a view controller - now I have added a view controller and return yes for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation its all good. Thanks